# The kerning option of microtype

Tags: microtype, kerning, package-options

I wonder what the kerning option of the microtype package does? [In the manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/microtype/microtype.pdf) it says that `kerning=true` will give additional kerning. But how? Is this something that has to be specified in addition to activating the option?

I can see no visual difference or any difference in filesize when compiling the two following examples with pdfTeX-1.40.10. Example 1:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[kerning=true]{microtype}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Example 2:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[kerning=false]{microtype}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: My opinion is, switch off everything except **Character protrusion**. Most of the typographers agree, that **Font expansion** distorts the font. Personally, I see it, and I agree - the distortion is quite visible for the trained reader. **Tracking/letterspacing** changes the color of the words. It's especially confusing in the Cyrillic typography, where _spacing out_ is used for emphasis instead of italics - [soul package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/soul/soul.pdf).

Comment: @KarlKarlsson I've asked a question about the greatest value for font expansion for which distortion is not noticeable: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30949/set-font-expansion-so-that-its-not-noticeable

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`kerning` is not a "true-false" option. Its purpose is to add some kerning independently of the adjacent letters, for example to set the French semicolon that needs a space before it. However it's not working well: for example, the colon requires a normal interword space before and after it, and this space should stretch or shrink along with the other spaces on the same line, which is impossible to get with kerning.

See section 5.4 in the manual of **microtype**.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the "kerning" option can indeed take the values "true" and "false". Since the "default" context does not actually add any extra kerning, these values have no effect unless the user modifies the "default" context.