# Set font expansion so that distortion is not noticeable

Tags: typography, microtype, font-expansion

In a comment to [The kerning option of microtype](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20793/the-kerning-option-of-microtype) Karl Karlsson writes:

> Most of the typographers agree, that **Font expansion** distorts the font.
>   Personally, I see it, and I agree - the distortion is quite visible
>   for the trained reader.

I've always thought font expansion was great because it reduced hyphenation and I haven't noticed any distortion. The reason that I haven't noticed any distortion is probably because I've read documents on screen or draft/economy mode inkjet prints. When I recently got a document printed on a laser printer I noticed the distortion and it was irritating. The font I noticed it for is Latin Modern in 12 pt with the default font expansion settings. Before I only had documents printed on laser printer as two pages per paper (same font and font size) and then I did not notice any distortion.

In the [microtype manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/microtype/microtype.pdf) I read that the amount of font expansion can be configured by changing stretchability and shrinkability of a font via `stretch` and `shrink` and that their default value is 20 (§3.3). My question is: what is the greatest value for font expansion for which distortion is not noticeable when printing documents on a laser printer? I haven't got a laser printer so it's hard for me to test different values. Also, I'd appreciate any information on fonts for which distortion due to font expansion is rarely noticeable.

Comment: I recently edited a book, using microtype’s standard value of font expansion (with Stempel Garamond), that was printed by a professional publisher, and I don’t see any distortion. That does not mean that there is nothing as such a distortion, but rather that I am also interested in this topic (c;

Comment: @domwass I haven't excluded that the laster printer from which I got the prints is faulty, but it would be strange if it caused problems that could be confused with distortion due to font expansion.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The following quote from section 9 of the microtype manual suggests that the package author was aware of potential negative effects of font expansion and viewed the default behaviour `stretch=20` as sensible:

> Expanding the fonts by more than 2%, i. e., setting a stretch limit of more than 20, should be justified by a typographically trained eye. If you are so lucky as to be in the possession of multiple instances of a Multiple Master font, you may set expansion limits to up to 4%.

Latin Modern (Computer Modern) -- and especially its design size of 12pt -- is a very "light" font, i.e., it has a high ratio of the width of the set of all lowercase letters, divided by the stem width ([A short introduction to font characteristics](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb20-2/tb63geld.pdf)). Therefore, it may well be that `microtype`s maximal expansion of +/-2% is less suited for Latin Modern than for "darker" fonts like Times.

In section 9.4 of [The Elements of Typographic Style](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0881792063), Robert Bringhurst demonstrates (and by implication issues the blessing to) font expansion of +/-2%. (The book's text face is Minion Pro, apparently a "darker" font compared to Latin Modern.)

Comment: Is there any convention or recommendations for font expansion of Computer/Latin Modern, e.g. recommended values for `stretch` and `shrink`?

Comment: @N.N.: AFAIK, `microtype` features only "tailored" protrusion settings for certain fonts.