# Should I load microtype with pdflatex?

Tags: pdftex, typography, microtype

Should I always load the `microtype` package with `pdflatex`?

Could it produce unwanted effects a naive user (like me) might ignore?

Are there any known issues as for compatibility with other packages?

In fact, I can't see any differences in the appearance of the output but I came across some posts which say that microtype is essentially a must for pdflatex since it greatly improves the pdf output.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20793/5701 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30949/5701

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Always use it, it should improve full justification. If you want, you can tinker with the variables for expansion and protrusion. A good example where you can see what microtype does is [here](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/layout/pdflatex-microtype/). Also the microtype documentation provides an interactive example of what each option does.

Comment: Interactive example sounds good ... just can't find it!?

Comment: look on page 4, the first section. On the left side are two buttons, try to press them.

Comment: Great, thanks! The margin of the doc wasn't displayed since my window was not wide enough ;-)

Comment: Indeed I also suggest to always load it - but further you should also add `\makeatletter\usepackage{microtype}\g@addto@macro\@verbatim{\microtypesetup{activate=false}}\makeatother%` to you preamble to avoid problems with verbatim-areas.

Comment: What packages were used in the Microtype documentation? - I'd like to experiment with interactivity in a PDF.

Comment: @johntait.org IIRC ocg layers. You can view and hide different layers when clicking on a button or printing vs displaying.

Comment: @BastianEbeling, the microtype documentation suggests to use `\AtBeginEnvironment{verbatim}{\microtypesetup{activate=false}}`, do you know the difference?

Comment: @Turion I'm not perfekt sure, but I think, the result is the same. My solution is just that old, the hook @AtBeginEnvironment{verbatim} was not available.

Comment: @BastianEbeling, maybe your version works for `\verbatim` commands as well?

Comment: @Turion, I'm sure yes, that will work. You're right: Thus it is not identical.

Answer (score 18):

The answer is: yes, load it, but use not everywhere. For example, microtype should be avoided in the table of contents (which is actually stated in the documentation of the package). In addition to the original documentation, [here](http://khirevich.com/latex/microtype/) you can find illustrated examples addressing different microtype features.

Comment: Nice reference.